# How to product counts by click plus button and minus button in magento 2

Tags: customer-account

I tried plus and minus buttons for product counts increase and decrease in proceed to checkout dropdown menu but i can't. Can anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Which magento version, on which page cart page?

Comment: You have to update cart on click of +/- buttons in js. please share your code where you have written.

Comment: D:\xampp\htdocs\magento_new\pub\static\frontend\Hiddentechies\bentriz\en_US\Magento_Checkout\template\minicart\item
<span class="qty-main">
                                <span class="qty-btn qty-inc"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="qty-btn qty-dec"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </span>
This path I have copied from addtocart.phtml.